# Create MongoDB collection with standard JSON schema

Tags: json, mongodb

I want to create a MongoDB collection using an JSON schema file.

Suppose the JSON file `address.schema.json` contain address information schema ([this file is one of the Json-schema.org's examples](https://json-schema.org/learn/examples/address.schema.json)):

```
{
  "$id": "https://example.com/address.schema.json",
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "description": "An address similar to http://microformats.org/wiki/h-card",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "post-office-box": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "extended-address": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "street-address": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "locality": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "region": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "postal-code": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "country-name": {
      "type": "string"
    }
  },
  "required": [ "locality", "region", "country-name" ],
  "dependencies": {
    "post-office-box": [ "street-address" ],
    "extended-address": [ "street-address" ]
  }
}
```

What is the MongoDB command, such as [mongoimport](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/schema-validation/) or [db.createCollection](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/schema-validation/) to create a MongoDB collection using the above schema?

It can be nice if I can use the file directly in MongoDB with the need of changing the file format manually.

I wonder if the JSON schema format is a standard one, why do I need to change it to adopt it for MongoDB. Why MongoDB does not have this functionality built-in?

Answer (score 2):

You can create it via `createCollection` command or shell helper:

```
db.createCollection(
    "mycollection", 
    {validator:{$jsonSchema:{
        "description": "An address similar to http://microformats.org/wiki/h-card",
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
           "post-office-box": {       "type": "string"     },
           "extended-address": {       "type": "string"     },
           "street-address": {       "type": "string"     },
           "locality": {       "type": "string"     },
           "region": {       "type": "string"     },
           "postal-code": {       "type": "string"     },
           "country-name": {       "type": "string"     } 
        },
        "required": [ "locality", "region", "country-name" ],
        "dependencies": {
            "post-office-box": [ "street-address" ],
            "extended-address": [ "street-address" ]
        } 
  }}})
```

You only need to specify `bsonType` instead of `type` if you want to use a type that exists in `bson` but not in generic json schema.  You do have to remove the lines `$id` and `$schema` as those are not supported by MongoDB JSON schema support ([documented here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/jsonSchema/#omissions))

Answer (score -1):

The only option which you can use is adding jsonSchema validator during collection creating: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/jsonSchema/#document-validator. It will mean that any document which you will insert/update in your collection will have to match with the provided schema

Comment: Can you write the complete command for the example in the question?

Comment: I don't have a lot of experience in this stuff, but looking at the doc example https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/jsonSchema/#schema-validation, your schema should have a bit different format.

Comment: yes, the difference in format is what puzzling me. I wonder if the JSON schema format is a standard format, why should I change it in MongoDB. Why not use it directly?

Comment: I guess it's because `bsonType` is not equal to `jsonType` and as a result the available options can be different. However see notes here(`MongoDB supports draft 4 of JSON Schema`): https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/jsonSchema/#op._S_jsonSchema. Not 100% sure what it means, but you can check, maybe your schema also works.

Comment: I dont understand what is the datatype Mongo using when passing validation parameters. BSON is a binary format isn't it? so I guess it is not BSONType. Seems like a mixture of JSON and BSON

Comment: bson is a type very similar to json(but with some additional types), but this type will be encoded into binary format during sending to the server.